# why is DBL_MAX inconsistent in C++ builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am using the evaluation version of Embarcadero RAD Studio. I get different values of DBL_MAX for code in a static library, and code in the main app.

The code is

double x = DBL_MAX;

In the code in the static library x is assigned the incorrect value ~1.449E-125. In the code in the main app x is assigned the correct value ~1.79E+308.

My first thought was that the library code was #including something that was defining the value incorrectly, but I can't find any such definition in any of its sources or headers.

Another idea I had is that there may be some problem with the initialization of std:_max_dble, which is used in the definition of DBL_MAX.

To reproduce the problem, I created a C++ Builder static library (on Windows 7) using this source only:

```
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <float.h>
double TestDblMax()
    {
    double x(DBL_MAX);
    return x;
    }
```

linked the library to a VCL forms app, and called it from the form constructor, as the first statement in that constructor. It gave the result ~1.449E-125.

Comment: How do you know the value? Try not assigning it, but print it directly from the library like `void printDblMax() { cout << DBL_MAX; }`. It may be an issue with initialization order or bad linking.

Comment: I know the values because I examined them in the debugger after setting breakpoints. (Please note that I'm not in the habit of posting questions without carefully checking my facts first.) These are automatic stack variables in functions and so are initialised when the function is executed.

Comment: @GrahamAsher: Actually, as far as the Standard is concerned, they do not need to be initialized when the function is executed, but only when they're needed for an observable operation - such as `std::cout << x`. And even then a compiler may just replace it with `std::cout << DBL_MAX` as there would be no observable difference - debuggers don't count.

Comment: I think you need to prove that there is a problem with an SSCCE

Comment: In the debug version, values of variables are reliable. Further, the value mentioned was used in code, and I examined it when it was actually used. The fact that it had an incorrect value caused a bug, which was why I started looking into it. The bug is in a large commercial library which runs perfectly on other platforms.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I assume that SSCCE is some sort of abbreviation for  a minimal test case. I have just added that (see above).

Comment: You should certainly do a websearch for SSCCE. Very important knowledge there. But yes, your update is excellent. It does look like a rather shocking compiler bug. I think you will need to be specific about the compiler version.

Comment: The compiler is the standard compiler that comes with Embarcadero C++ Builder for Windows. I changed no options relating to the compiler.

Comment: There have been countless different releases of that product. Anyway, if it is a compiler bug, only Emba can fix it. Submit a QC report.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: okay, fair point, but I've been round the block on this and haven't the time. I already have a work-around.

Comment: I'm not giving orders. I'll let you work it out for yourself then.

Comment: I just re-read your comment after you removed the part about orders. It's a shame that you don't care enough to submit a QC report. It won't take long and could help others.

Comment: I've done a lot on this already. I tried to find a way to submit a bug report and gave up after a while. I am developing and marketing a commercial product on six different platforms, working 8 or 9 intensive hours a day. If people have this problem they will no doubt google for it and find my remarks. Of course I am now far less motivated to use Stack Overflow, which would be a nicer place if there was less questioning of people's competence and motivation. In my answers I never do that, and I advise others to adopt the same approach. I come to Stack Overflow as a last resort now.

Answer (score 2):

Found this old post as "unanswered". I did some testing using C++Builder 10.4 Sydney.

If I use the C++ classic compiler - then I get the same output you did for DBL_MAX ~1.449E-125 using a static library and a VCL app.

When I tested using Win32 (and turning off the compiler option "Use 'classic' Borland compiler) to use the Clang based compiler then I get the correct result for DBL_MAX ~1.79E+308. I also tested with the Clang based Win64 compiler and get the correct result for DBL_MAX.

Will have to ask the C++ compiler team if they remember an issue with the classic compiler and DBL_MAX.